# Backup Software Sources

Tags: ppa, apt, aptitude, synaptic, gnupg

In Ubuntu 10.04, when I goto System > Administration > Software Sources and goto the Authentication tab, I can view all of my keys allowing me to download from third party sources.

How would I back this up to copy all of my sources and keys to a new system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method to backup your sources list has [already been described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2038/backup-software-sources/2039#2039) by garbagecollector (also note the additional directory as explained by [Javier Rivera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2038/backup-software-sources/2043#2043)).

To backup the trusted keys added to your system you can use the apt-key command line program. I don't know if there is a way to do this from the GUI.

From a terminal you can run something like this:

```
sudo apt-key exportall > ~/repositories.key
```

Then on your other system you should be able to import that key file from Software Sources or you can use apt-key again:

```
sudo apt-key add /path/to/repositories.key
```

I only have one Ubuntu desktop system so I haven't tested this out, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 3):

From 10.04 the source list can be in different places, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` as said before and all the files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

The keys are stored in a similar fashion, the file `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` and the files inside `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`

Finally you will need the info in trustdb.gpg to be able to decrypt the keys.

You will need to copy all these files and dirs.

Edit: **The best way to copy the keys is explained in another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2038/backup-software-sources/2042#2042). So please copy only sources.list and all the files inside sources.list.d**. I keep the info about the files placement in the case it proves useful to another person.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would help backing up your sources.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
```

Then do the reverse when you are your new system.

Maybe also try this [software](http://www.le-web.org/back-in-time/). Although I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I have tried backing up all of my sources lists but I get this error for each source I have: `W: GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E`