# Is it possible to create an installation disk of Ubuntu, from an already existing installation?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use existing Ubuntu partition as an installation image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13869/use-existing-ubuntu-partition-as-an-installation-image)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, and wondering if it is possible to create an installation disk/image from my existing installation.

I need to install it on my friend's PC. I'm just wondering, can it be done, or do I have to download the whole installation again?

> If any are wondering why I would bother to do this, it is just because
>   Internet speed here isn't any good, monthly quota is pretty low, and
>   the prices are even worse.

Comment: Have a look at  the top answer: [Use existing Ubuntu partition as an installation image?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13869/use-existing-ubuntu-partition-as-an-installation-image)

Comment: I found that question on the right side when I opened yours ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remastersys, it is free tool for it 
you can install it via ppa

You can find more info here [remastersys forum](http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php)

Installation instructions quoted from remastersys forum.

> The Synaptic Method:
>
> 1. In Firefox, go to:
>
>    http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key
>      save file as text someplace where you can find it.
> 2. In synaptic, go to Settings/Repositories; select "Authentication" tab and "Import Key File" just downloaded.
> 3. Still in synaptic, go to "Other Software" tab and click "Add", then enter the apt line and replace oneiric with either lucid,
>      maverick, or natty to match your Ubuntu version:
>
>    deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu oneiric main
> 4. Leave the repositories tab and "Reload".
> 5. Search for "remastersys" and select for install.  Edit/Apply Marked Changes.
>
> The Manual Method
>
> Download and apply the repository signing key.
>
> ```
> wget -O - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list, substituting "oneiric"
>   for your Ubuntu version (e.g. lucid, natty, maverick)
>
> ```
> deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu oneiric main
> ```
>
> Now just `sudo apt-get update` or reload in Synaptic to have the new
>   Remastersys signed repository ready to use!

Answer (score 4):

We used to commercial package [Acronis true image live cd](http://www.google.com.et/search?aq=0&oq=acroni&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=acronis%20true%20image) to take one Ubuntu computer full image and deploy onto another computer.

But there is a good alternative for Acronic live CD. That is  [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)

- Donwnload from here -> [Clonezilla live ISO file](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)
- Burn it on CD
- Prepare external Hard disc to take your computer image.
- and, follow the steps to take a backup and restore. Refer this [Doc](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) for more info.

Comment: but if it takes an exact image of my installation, won't that create some trouble on the other PC I'm installing it on? (I'm using a Sony Vaio Laptop, while he is using a custom built desktop PC)

Comment: It will format the other PC

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Check this article..
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872

Think this will be helpful.

Comment: This may therocticaly answer the problem but askubuntu you should post the steps instead of just posting link 
visit faq again :)