# Backup sources and setting for reinstall

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

I currently have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my laptop.  Configured just the way I like it.  Now I need to reinstall everything because I have a need to encrypt my whole hard drive and on Ubuntu, that can only be done using the alternate CD.  Question is what would be a good way to reinstall everything including sources and PPA's after encryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find some removable medium, e.g. a flash drive.
2. Save `/etc/apt/sources.list` and every file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to it.
3. Open System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager. Go to File > Save Markings As... , check the box labeled "Save full state, not only changes", and save it to the removable medium. This file is basically a list of every single package you have installed.

Once you've reinstalled:

1. Restore your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to the computer.
2. Open Synaptic again, and press Reload.
3. Still in Synaptic, go to File > Read Markings. Open the markings file you saved previously. Then press Apply, sit back, and relax.

Comment: I found this script at http://www.khattam.info/howto-install-all-the-packages-installed-in-one-ubuntu-installation-to-another-2010-11-12.html.  Worked great.