# Where is the PPA sources config file?

Tags: package-management, ppa

I have added three PPAs.
How do I backup their configuration?

Where is the PPA config file?

Comment: What do you mean by "PPA Config File"?

Comment: I do not find ppa address of 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox' in /etc/apt/sources.list . Where does it be kept ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PPAs tend to be added into their own files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Here is an extract from a `ls` in that directory on this system:

```
am-monkeyd-nautilus-elementary-ppa-maverick.list
am-monkeyd-nautilus-elementary-ppa-maverick.list.save
awn-testing-ppa-maverick.list
awn-testing-ppa-maverick.list.save
banshee-team-banshee-unstable-maverick.list
banshee-team-banshee-unstable-maverick.list.save
banshee-team-ppa-maverick.list
```

If you're trying to move these to another system or back them up, just using these files is not the best idea because these files have version specific strings in them. [Look at my answer on another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28644/how-can-i-backup-my-ppas/28655#28655). It will generate a list of PPA strings that you can add back manually (or with a little script that just loops the list).

Comment: You'd probably want to backup the keys as well.

Comment: The benefit of [my answer to the other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28644/how-can-i-backup-my-ppas/28655#28655) is it give you strings that lend themselves to being piped them through `add-apt-repository` (which grabs all the keys for you, as you're re-adding them).