# How can I get a list of all repositories and PPAs from the command line into an install script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ppa, repository, add-apt-repository

I know how to [list all packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) installed on my system.

**But how could I get a list of all repositories and PPA's into a script that I can run on a new machine to replicate the repository setup including the keys?**

I know I can look into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, but I'm looking for a way to **generate** a script that executes all `apt-add-repository` commands on a new system (that sorts out getting all keys).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers. With a little cleanup I got a script that lists the PPAs, but not any other repository:

`listppas` script:

```sh
#! /bin/sh 

# listppas Script to get all the PPAs installed on a system ready to share for
# reininstall

for APT in `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list`; do
    grep -o "^deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9\-]\+/[a-z0-9\-]\+" $APT \
            | while read ENTRY ; do
        USER=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f4`
        PPA=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f5`
        echo sudo apt-add-repository ppa:$USER/$PPA
    done
done
```

When you call it with `listppas > installppas.sh` you get an `installppas.sh` script you can copy onto a new machine to reinstall all PPAs.

Next stop: do that for the other repositories:

Final `listppas` script:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# Script to get all the PPAs which are installed on a system

for APT in `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list`; do
    grep -Po "(?<=^deb\s).*?(?=#|$)" $APT | while read ENTRY ; do
        HOST=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f3`
        USER=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f4`
        PPA=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f5`
        #echo sudo apt-add-repository ppa:$USER/$PPA
        if [ "ppa.launchpad.net" = "$HOST" ]; then
            echo sudo apt-add-repository ppa:$USER/$PPA
        else
            echo sudo apt-add-repository \'${ENTRY}\'
        fi
    done
done
```

This should do the trick. Use it as `listppas > installppas.sh` on the source machine, then run the contents of `installppas.sh` on the destination machine.

I needed a [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/434939/match-a-line-until-a-but-without-the-when-parsing-a-file-with-a-regex) to figure out the correct regex.

Comment: In your `grep -o` example, the `\\``  in `[a-z0-9\-]` is not doing what you expect.  It actually matches  a literal *backslash*. You don't need to *escape* the `-` when it is at the start or end of the `[]` list; actually, you can't *escape* it!..  In this case the `\\`` (probably) won't cause a problem, because you (hopefully) won't encounter a *backslash* in the `deb` entry.

Comment: Note that PPA names may contain dots, so I think you want to change your regexp to `http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9-]\+/[a-z0-9.-]\+`

Comment: No, you want to change the regex to `[[:graph:]] ` instead of `[a-z...blah.anything]` because that will match any alphanumeric + punctuation characters - that is what the PPA names consist of.

Comment: I suppose you should include `deb` word in the beginning of each repository line, if not given in `ppa:$USER/$PPA` form.

Comment: @stwissel any particular reason you used find and then grep? You can easily do a glob that the shell parses and pass it to grep. `grep -Po "(?<=^deb\s).*?(?=#|$)" /etc/apt/{sources.list,sources.list.d/*.list} | while read ENTRY ; do echo $ENTRY; done` Note that as written this shows you the file name each entry comes from so you'd need to do a trim from the beginning of the result to the first colon, but that isn't too hard with cut. You may also want to pass it through `uniq` if you don't want multiple entries for the same source (eg if you have Google Chrome Stable/Beta/Dev installed).

Comment: @dragon788 Thx for the pointer. I used find mainly because that's what I knew ;-). You are very welcome to add an answer with a complete script, so visitors to this post have options to choose from

Comment: Use apt-cache policy; there's an answer below which illustrates how, and which should be marked the best answer. That shows what apt is actually using, and in what priority.

Comment: @kiko: the answer you refer to produces a list, not a script as asked

Comment: All my ppas were unauthorized after using installppa.sh, had to add them back manually for them to grab their keys.

Answer (score 263):

You can show everything with:

```
grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Comment: What about `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to remove lines commented out and blank lines?

Comment: could you please explain the use of `^` after `grep` in `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: @vasa1 The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are metacharacters that  respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.

Comment: wojox, @vasa1: thx for the contribution. It helped to get clarity how to sort this out.

Comment: I use grep ^[^#] ... -- It auto-hides all commented-out sources

Comment: If you're not going to filter anything out, wouldn't it be simpler to just run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: Maybe you'd want to use the regex `^[^#]`.

Comment: What does this line do?

Comment: Using `grep ^` instead of `cat` is super confusing.

Comment: using
# grep "^deb"  /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
gave me a shorter info

Answer (score 49):

I am surprised that the simplest but most effective way to get all enabled binary software sources together with the file they're specified in hasn't been posted yet:

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

From all processed files, this will print every line starting with `deb`. This excludes commented lines as well as `deb-src` lines to enable source code repositories.

It searches really only all `*.list` files that will be parsed by `apt`, but e.g. no `*.list.save` files used for backup or others with illegal names.

---

If you want a shorter but possibly only in 99.9% of all cases correct output that may search too much files (includes all `/etc/apt/sources.list*` files and directories, not only `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*), you could also use this:

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

Unless there are files that shouldn't be there, the output will be the same.

---

An example output on my machine would be this:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/maarten-fonville-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/ppa/ubuntu wily main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-wily.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu wily main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-indicator-sysmonitor-wily.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor/ubuntu wily main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb apps
```

---

If you want prettier output, let's pipe it through `sed`:

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'
```

And we will see this:

```
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security universe
deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu/ wily-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
[maarten-fonville-ubuntu-ppa-wily.list] ppa:maarten-fonville/ppa
[webupd8team-ubuntu-tor-browser-wily.list] ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
[fossfreedom-ubuntu-indicator-sysmonitor-wily.list] ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
[getdeb.list] deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb apps
```

Comment: Going by the accepted answer, it seems OP wanted PPAs to be shown in the `ppa:<user>/<project>` form.

Comment: The question actually asks to generate a script that installs/enables all repositories. But the question title is only about listing them. Also the 2nd highest scored answer only lists them as well, but it lists far too much.

Comment: Nice, but I'd already upvoted. :D

Comment: You could use ` -h` option for grep to leave out the file names.

Answer (score 34):

Run the following command:

```
apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | sort -u
```

[Source](http://ask.xmodulo.com/list-installed-repositories-ppas-ubuntu.html)

Comment: In bionic this prints lines such as 'http://mirrors.nic.funet.fi/ubuntubionic-security/main'

Comment: Note: `apt-cache policy` will only show the repos after you have run `apt-get update`. If you just added a repo with `add-apt-repository`, it will not show up with `apt-cache policy` until you run `apt-get update`

Comment: Per @wisbucky :  
`sudo apt update > /dev/null 2>&1 && sudo apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2 $3}' | sort -u` works well.  
https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/229da822f1f02157bff192a2e4a8ffd1

Comment: `apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2 " " $3}'` will mean that there's a space between the mirror and the suite, i.e. `http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main`

Answer (score 9):

Here is my script, "`list-apt-repositories`", which lists all repositories in "`/etc/sources.list"` and "`/etc/sources.list.d/*.list`". You can add `--ppa-only` to show only the PPAs. PPAs are automatically transformed to `ppa:USER/REPO` format.

The relevant parts are the 5 lines in `list_sources` and `list_ppa` functions, the rest is just boilerplate to wrap it in a handy shell script.

### `list-apt-repositories`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage () {
  cat >&2 <<USAGE
$0 [--ppa-only]

Options:
  --ppa-only            only list PPAs
USAGE
  exit $1
}

list_sources () {
  grep -hE '^deb\s' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list |\
    sed '/ppa/ s/deb //g' |\
    sed -re 's#http://ppa\.launchpad\.net/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*?)$#ppa:\1/\2#g'
}

list_ppa () {
  list_sources | grep '^ppa:'
}

generate=list_sources

while test -n "$1"
do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help) usage 1;;
    --ppa-only) generate=list_ppa;;
    *)
      printf -- "Unknown argument '$1'\n" >&2
      usage 2
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

$generate
```

And to make an install script, pipe into another script "`make-apt-repository-install-script`". The generated script supports the `-y`/`--yes` argument for non-interactive use (see `add-apt-repository(1)`).

### `make-apt-repository-install-script`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if test -n "$1"
then
  cat >&2 <<USAGE
Usage: $0 < PATH_TO_LIST_OF_REPOS
       list-apt-repositories [--ppa-only] | $0

No options recognized.

Reads list of repositories from stdin and generates a script to install them
using \`add-apt-repository(1)\`. The script is printed to stdout.

The generated script supports an optional
\`-y\` or \`--yes\` argument which causes the \`add-apt-repository\` commands
to be run with the \`--yes\` flag.
USAGE
  exit 1
fi

cat <<INSTALL_SCRIPT
#!/bin/sh
y=
case "\$1" in
  -y|--yes) y=\$1;;
  '') y=;;
  *)
    printf '%s\n' "Unknown option '\$1'" "Usage: \$0 [{-y|--yes}]" >&2
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
INSTALL_SCRIPT

xargs -d'\n' printf "add-apt-repository \$y '%s'\n"
```

Again, the important part is the `xargs` command on the last line, the rest is boilerplate.

Comment: Let me know if the changes conflict with the install script. `deb ` is needed when using `add-apt-repository` to add repositories that use `[arch=amd64]` before the URL, like Google. This way, `deb ` is included for all non-ppa repos.

Answer (score 7):

Using `add-apt-repository` from [`software-properties-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/software-properties-common), it is as simple as:

```
add-apt-repository --list
```

The output can easily be supplied back to `add-apt-repository` command to recreate the sources.

However, it only lists `deb` sources. If you are interested also in `ppa`s, then the other answers on this question will be more useful.

##### Availability

It appears that the `--list` option was only available since version 0.99.0+ of `software-properties-common`, which is available by default starting from Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy). So you will either need to update your version of the software, or upgrade your distro to atleast 20.10.

Comment: There is not such option `--list` on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @s.ouchene I'm on 21.10 impish, so that option may have been recently added

Comment: You may need to add your Ubuntu version to your post.

Comment: @s.ouchene done

Comment: Works on 22.04 lts

Answer (score 4):

I use this command to list all configured software sources (repositories), *including currently disabled ones*:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list; for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done
```

I use this primarily for troubleshooting; this can certainly be incorporated into scripts but you may want to narrow `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` so you only get currently enabled software sources.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. cat lists the files as they are, so I would need to manually edit it to *generate* a script (as stated in the question). The challenge with repositories: if you just copy the files from /etc/apt you don't get the repository keys. This is why I want a script that fetches them for us

Answer (score 3):

So, doing some digging, we have `AptPkg::Class`.

So using `perl` we can do something simple like this..

```
perl -MAptPkg::Cache -MData::Dumper -E'say Dumper [AptPkg::Cache->new->files()]' | less
```

This gets us a list of all the `AptPkg::Class::PkgFile` packages. You could probably generate the `apt-add-repository` commands with that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner:

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list* -type f -iname "*.list" -exec grep -viE '(^#|^$)' {} \; -print | column -tx
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic            main        restricted
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic-updates    main        restricted
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic            universe
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic-updates    universe
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic            multiverse
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic-updates    multiverse
deb                                 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    bionic-backports  main        restricted  universe  multiverse
deb                                 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   bionic-security   main        restricted
deb                                 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   bionic-security   universe
deb                                 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   bionic-security   multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list
deb                                 https://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/  bionic            nginx
deb-src                             https://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/  bionic            nginx
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

Comment: That doesn’t output a shell script - see the question

Answer (score 3):

*Ripgrep* version for completeness:

```
rg --iglob '*.list' '^deb(-src)? ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Answer (score 2):

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ will give you a list of all PPAs for your version of Ubuntu. Here is a generated list without source files and no samsung printer ppa:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                           UNOFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### Flacon PPA - http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=113388
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2A61FE5
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flacon/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main

#### Gimp PPA - https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 614C4B38
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu yakkety main

#### Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

#### Google Earth - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main

#### Highly Explosive PPA - https://launchpad.net/~dhor/+archive/myway
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93330B78
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dhor/myway/ubuntu yakkety main

#### JDownloader PPA - https://launchpad.net/~jd-team
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6A68F637
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu yakkety main

#### Lazarus - http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/
## Run this command:  gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:11371 --recv-keys 6A11800F  && gpg --export --armor 0F7992B0  | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/ lazarus-stable universe

#### LibreOffice PPA - http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main

#### MEGA Sync Client - https://mega.co.nz/
deb http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.10/ ./

#### MKVToolnix - http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/
## Run this command: wget -q http://www.bunkus.org/gpg-pub-moritzbunkus.txt -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://www.bunkus.org/ubuntu/yakkety/ ./

#### Mozilla Daily Build Team PPA - http://edge.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  247510BE
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main

#### muCommander - http://www.mucommander.com/
## Run this command: sudo wget -O - http://apt.mucommander.com/apt.key | sudo apt-key add - 
deb http://apt.mucommander.com stable main non-free contrib  

#### Opera - http://www.opera.com/
## Run this command: sudo wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

#### Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety main

#### PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/
## Run this command: wget -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu yakkety-getdeb games

#### SABnzbd PPA - http://sabnzbd.org/
## Run this command:  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4BB9F05F
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main

#### SimpleScreenRecorder PPA - http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 283EC8CD
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu yakkety main

#### Steam for Linux - http://store.steampowered.com/about/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
deb [arch=i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam

#### Syncthing - https://syncthing.net/
## Run this command: curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release

#### Tor: anonymity online - https://www.torproject.org
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 886DDD89
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org yakkety main

#### Unsettings PPA - http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0FEB6DD9
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu yakkety main

#### VirtualBox - http://www.virtualbox.org
## Run this command: wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian yakkety contrib

#### Webmin - http://www.webmin.com
## Run this command: wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib

#### WebUpd8 PPA - http://www.webupd8.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4C9D234C
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu yakkety main

#### Xorg Edgers PPA - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542  
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main
here is a generated list without source files and no samsung printer ppa
#### Yuuguu - http://yuuguu.com
deb http://update.yuuguu.com/repositories/apt hardy multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

To have it add ppa.launchpad.net lines as ppa:$USER/$PPA. Add other repositories with their full line from *.list files. No dupe lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
# My ~/bin/mk_repositories_restore_script
mkdir -p ~/bin 
x=~/bin/restore_repositories
echo \#\!/bin/bash > $x
chmod u+x $x
(
 for APT in $( find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list )
    do sed -n -e '/^deb /{
     /ppa\.launchpad/s/\(.*\/\/[^\/]*.\)\([^ \t]*\)\(.*$\)/sudo apt-add-repository ppa:\2/p;
     /ppa\.launchpad/!s/\(deb[ \t]*\)\(.*$\)/sudo apt-add-repository \2/p;
    }' $APT
 done
) | sort | uniq | tee -a ~/bin/restore_repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks BobDodds!

If anybody would be interested, I have updated your code a little (hope you don't mind)..

This script will type out only user added PPAs (/etc/apt/sources.list.d).

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # My ~/bin/mk_repositories_restore_script
    mkdir -p ~/bin
    x=~/bin/restore_repositories
    echo \#\!/bin/bash > $x
    chmod u+x $x
    (
    for APT in $( find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list )
    do sed -n -e '/^deb /{
          /ppa\.launchpad/s/\(.*\/\/[^\/]*.\)\([^ \t]*\)\(.*\/ubuntu.*$\)/ppa:\2/p;                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }' $APT
    done
    ) | sort | uniq | tee -a ~/bin/restore_repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r -e '/^deb /!d' -e 's/^([^#]*).*/\1/' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.+)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/' -e "s/.*/sudo add-apt-repository '&'/" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

That does not generate commands to enable possible source repositories (deb-src) though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to list the repositories, I will provide a short method similar to some already posted, also filtering out comments using a regex: **^[^#]** ("at the line start, no commented lines"):

```
grep "^[^#]" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Answer (score -3):

Install `ppa-purge`

```
apt install ppa-purge
```

Then get ppa list by tab completion...

`ppa-purge -o` (hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice)

Comment: That's kinda backwards. How do you suggest OP collect the shell completion output for storage or processing? Also, `ppa-purge` has no `-o` flag according to [its manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html). -1