# list all the ppa repositories added to my system

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, repository

How can I list all the ppa repositories added to my system and save it to a `.txt` file, so that I don't want to spend my time in searching for ppa's for fresh installations and i can just select a ppa line in my `.txt` file and append to the command  `sudo add-apt-repository`? Also is there any other ways to do this in which i dont want to give the gpg keys manually?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [How can I get a list of all repositories and PPAs from the command line into an install script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148932/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-repositories-and-ppas-from-the-command-line)

Part of the answer looks to have what you are looking for:

```sh
#! /bin/sh 
# listppa Script to get all the PPA installed on a system ready to share for reininstall
for APT in `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list`; do
    grep -o "^deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9\-]\+/[a-z0-9\-]\+" $APT | while read ENTRY ; do
        USER=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f4`
        PPA=`echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f5`
        echo sudo apt-add-repository ppa:$USER/$PPA
    done
done
```

Save this as `listppa.sh`

```
listppa.sh > installppa.sh
```

This creates a script that you can backup somewhere, then run to add your PPAs on a fresh install by simply running:

```
installppa.sh
```

Answer (score 22):

For those who just want to check the PPAs they have installed without actually *doing* anything with them automatically you can do:

```
$ apt-cache policy
```

In my system, here's a bit of what it shows:

```
% apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http: ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main Translation-en
 500 http: ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=precise,n=precise,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http: ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=precise,n=precise,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http: ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/scudcloud/ubuntu/ precise/main Translation-en
 500 http: ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/scudcloud/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-rael-gc-scudcloud,a=precise,n=precise,l=ScudCloud - Linux client for Slack,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
...
```

Quoted from [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/list-installed-repositories-ppas-ubuntu.html):

> [`apt-cache policy`] retrieves priorities associated with each repository resource. From
>   its output, you can infer a list of all available repositories and
>   PPAs.

Source: http://ask.xmodulo.com/list-installed-repositories-ppas-ubuntu.html

Comment: This is nice and simple, however the output also includes Ubuntu base repositories. If you're going to do that you may as well use the full, final command used in the link you gave as your source: `apt-cache policy | grep http | awk '{print $2 $3}' | sort -u`. The output is better organized and easier on the eyes.

Comment: Note: `apt-cache policy` will only show the repos after you have run `apt-get update`. If you just added a repo with `add-apt-repository`, it will not show up with `apt-cache policy` until you run `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

From [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/982965/745345) on [How can I get a list of all repositories and PPAs from the command line into an install script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/148932/745345)

**List PPAs in `ppa:USER/REPO` format:**

```sh
grep -E '^deb\s' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list |\
  cut -f2- -d: |\
  cut -f2 -d' ' |\
  sed -re 's#http://ppa\.launchpad\.net/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*?)$#ppa:\1/\2#g' |\
  grep '^ppa:'
```

**List all repositories including PPAs in `ppa:USER/REPO` format:**

Just remove the last `grep` (don't forget to remove the `|\` from the previous line after  the`sed` command).

See my answer on the other question for full scripts you can save and use, including generating an install script.