# Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 unable to locate packages within jammy-updates repository

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

While installing `frescobaldi` version 3.3.0 in Jammy 22.04 I had to install 2 dependency packages, namely `python3-poppler-qt5`and `python3-qpageview`. I had no problem installing `python3-poppler-qt5`, however `python3-qpageview` which is only present in `jammy-updates` is labelled as '*not available*' ...

```
$ sudo apt install python3-qpageview
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-qpageview
$
```

This behaviour also happened minutes ago while trying to install `libevince-dev_42.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb` Ubuntu pretended I have a broken system ...

Previously I had installed [way earlier] `evince` and `evince-common` version 42.3 from `jammy-updates`. And this time Ubuntu was seeking to install the dev package for version 42.1 stock `jammy` instead of 42.3 ...

I guess that my Ubuntu did drop the capability to seek proper updates from`jammy-update` packages and I don't know how to restore the full capability. I don't see anything within `Software & Updates` to correct the trouble ...

Here is the result of `apt update` as requested

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for user: 
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable InRelease
[...]
Hit:40 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/variety/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:20 https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable Release.gpg
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 124F149833EAAB8E
Fetched 5,413 B in 10s (518 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 124F149833EAAB8E
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 124F149833EAAB8E
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$
```

[NOTE]: I have omitted a long list of ppa repositories.

An additional comment is that right before this kind of trouble did appear, I had a surprise one day to see `Synaptic` showing no green square anymore for installed packages ... I don't remember the step I took to get it back working in `Software & Updates`, but obviously not as before ...

`[Update on the posted answers]`: Sorry Sirs, but this is just pure noise ...

If my system was broken, I couldn't install any new packages, and that isn't the case. In addition Synaptic would flag any packages affected. Obviously this isn't the case either, period.

I didn't mention on my initial report that I successfully managed to install `python3-qpageview` & `frescobaldi` by command line. I thought it was obvious. But maybe not to everyone ?

So, comments like *`Your system is broken because you have a couple of bad repositories`* is totally without merit. In addition `jammy-updates`, or any distrib updates never shows up in any repository list following an `apt update` command.

All my PPAs installed are fully working. And I only get Warnings and Notifications, not a single Error following the `apt update`.

`About the Vivaldi NO_PUBKEY Error` : It looks like I am by far, not the only one affected by this behaviour, and according to the [Vivaldi Forum](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/42382/no_pubkey-error) it looks like there may be a bug within APT. This said, Vivaldi still updates properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Your system is broken because you have a couple of bad repositories in your package system. Clean that up before proceeding. You cut out the full output (why) but it looks like your package system is a hot mess. Perhaps it's in the output you cut out, but nothing you showed us proves that jammy-updates is in your package system. Consider editing your question to show the full h̶o̶r̶r̶o̶r̶ content of your sources.

Comment: To list all your sources you can run the command `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` in a terminal window. (from a comment to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/148954/243321)