# Fan speed: PPA for hardware/firmware

Tags: ppa, hardware, fan, fancontrol

I have an Acer Nitro 5, which, under Ubuntu, has a loud and hyperactive fan. I remember that I once added a PPA which has some firmware/drivers that could better deal with my hardware.

Yesterday, I re-installed Ubuntu (after a harddrive upgrade)... and the PPAs are lost.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: While I don't know about this particular PPA, this question may help you in future to back up PPAs https://askubuntu.com/q/28644/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thanks, but I think I'll just backup the /etc directory in future. It isn't that big, after all. :)