# Installing clang 6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic

Tags: 18.04, clang

How can I install clang on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic?

Comment: Add the results of `apt-cache policy clang clang-6.0 clang-5.0`

Comment: Please, post the output of `sudo apt install clang-6.0`...

Comment: `sudo apt install clang-6`. You can also do `sudo apt install clang-7` and `sudo apt install clang-8`

Answer (score 21):

`clang-6.0` is (at least currently) the default version of `clang` on Bionic:

```
$ apt-cache depends clang
clang
  Depends: clang-6.0
  Breaks: <clang-3.2>
  Breaks: <clang-3.3>
  Breaks: <clang-3.4>
  Breaks: <clang-3.5>
  Replaces: clang
  Replaces: <clang-3.2>
  Replaces: <clang-3.3>
  Replaces: <clang-3.4>
  Replaces: <clang-3.5>


$ apt-cache policy clang-6.0
clang-6.0:
  Installed: 1:6.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:6.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So, you just enable the universe repository and then install `clang` - either from the software store or from the command line using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clang
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang : Depends: clang-6.0 (>= 6.0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Comment: @steeldriver using the it I am getting the following error  **clang : Depends: clang-6.0 (>= 6.0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.** How to fix it ?

Comment: @NithinVarghese that's a rather generic error - there are some suggested fixes in this previous question [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) among others

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @steeldriver's answer, `clang` is a dependency package providing the default clang version, which is 6.0 in Bionic.

You may have better luck installing the `clang-6.0` package directly:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-6.0
```

Comment: Nope there was no lucking in  doing so.

Comment: @NithinVarghese You might need to ask your own question then showing the errors that you are getting.  I have a 18.04 LTS installation and I just barely installed it this way and it worked fine.  Without telling us errors, it is nearly next to impossible for us to guess what problems you are having during the installation.

Answer (score 4):

You can install `clang-6.0` on Ubuntu 18.04 using official LLVM repository.

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-6.0 main"

sudo apt update && sudo apt install clang-6.0
```

Comment: I've tired this method before and it was futile as others. Do you have any clue what can be the cause of this

Comment: I have tried and  it worked for me. Can you disable other repos and try again ?

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing some necessary channels from `sources.list`.

**Step 1:** [Backup your repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24022/how-can-i-backup-my-repositories) and remove repository lists other than `sources.list`.

**Step 2:** Do `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and make it look like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

Save and exit.

**Step 3:** Update your repository:

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step 4:** Install `clang-6.0`:

```
sudo apt install clang-6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as users above shared

```
sudo apt-get install clang-6.0
```

just that i want to pay your attention to this interesting [document : LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages](http://apt.llvm.org/)

to get a complete vision how to install **nightly packages**.

Answer (score 0):

Actualize by latest versions of the compiler:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install clang-9
sudo apt-get install clang-10
```