# dump dpkg package list for fresh installation

Tags: upgrade, apt, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

I've heard that I can dump the dpkg package list of currently installed applications, then after I re-install, re-import that list and have apt or dpkg do all the heavy lifting for me getting my apps re-installed.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To dump the list of currently installed applications:

```
dpkg --get-selections >output-file
```

To re-import:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections <output-file 
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: The one reason I hate doing this is it messes up the "automatically installed" feature of apt where unneeded dependencies can be removed but that may not be a big deal to normal users.

Comment: Why would it mess it up?

Comment: @matt because all packages installed with the third command result as manually installed, even if they were automatically installed in the original machine. The command `apt-mark` could be of help here.

Comment: @enzotib how exactly do you suggest using apt-mark? does this not assume one remembers which packages were automatically installed in the first place?

Comment: @matt: no, the information about the manual/automatic state of the packages is maintained somewhere in apt files. Also, in one of the answer to the question of which this is supposed to be a duplicate (see at top of page) is indicated `apt-clone` as a better solution to the whole problem we are facing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages/486634#486634

Comment: Wow, I wonder why apt-clone isn't the most commonly cited answer to being with...