# How to reset Unity to defaults?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I tried to activate some Compiz effect via CCSM (I think wobbly windows) and Compiz crashed and froze up the screen. So I used the Control+Alt+Backspace keystroke to force logout. Then I logged back in.

Unity wasn't there, just a (non-Unity) panel at the top with File, Edit, and the Like. I was able to pull up a terminal and launch ccsm, only to find almost all settings wiped out.

I turned everything back on that I thought should be on, but I don't know if I got everything. Also, now whenever I open up a non-maximized window, it opens up in the top left corner with the title bar behind the unity panel.

So what I need is a list of everything that needs to be on in ccsm, and a way to get windows to NOT open in the corner, preferably without having to reset Unity or Compiz.