# How can I make the Unity 2d Shell dodge GNOME Panel when running both simultaneously?

Tags: unity-2d, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

I'm using GNOME Fallback in 12.04, and I'm running the Unity 2D Shell (WITHOUT THE UNITY 2D PANEL) and GNOME Panel. I've done this by logging in using GNOME Fallback, and then running `unity-2d-shell`. This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

The second picture is my second monitor, ignore it.

As you can see, the gnome panel is on top of the Unity 2d shell. How can I move the Unity 2d shell 28 pixels from the top of the screen (my gnome panel is 28 pixels in height)?

Edit: I'm running Compiz as well, so I can use the ccsm if anyone has any solution that would require that.

Comment: curious - I deleted the bottom bar, run unity-2d-shell but the bar appears correctly placed :( have you tried running in gnome-classic (no effects) to see if the same thing occurs?

Comment: I don't experience this problem in gnome-classic with no effects, so I'm thinking it's a compiz issue.

Comment: hmmm - do you have place-windows ticked or not (try ticking/unticking) in ccsm.  Maybe its a plugin you have enabled/disabled.  Try resetting your compiz configuration to see if this helps... http://askubuntu.com/questions/70866/how-to-reset-compiz-unity-to-defaults

Comment: Neither of those did anything.

Comment: :( shame - well, I'm out of ideas... I hope someone else has an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that behavior would show up only for Compiz/Dual Display combination. What I've tested so far in VBox with Ubuntu 12.04 32bit:

- Metacity + Single Display (OK)
- Metacity + Dual Display (OK)
- Compiz + Single Display (OK)
- Compiz + Dual Display (Overlapping)

One trick or work around that works for me, adding a top panel to the second display & Auto hide should be disabled for both.

In case you don't want to add a panel to 2nd display, this another hack not fully tested, it just works:

1. Get source:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep unity-2d
   apt-get source unity-2d
   cd unity-2d-5.14.0/
   ```
2. Modify screen top

   `nano shell/app/shelldeclarativeview.cpp`

   ```
   void
   ShellDeclarativeView::updateShellPosition()
   {
   ...
       QRect my_screenInfo = m_screenInfo->availableGeometry();
       my_screenInfo.adjust(0,28,0,0);
       const QRect availableGeometry = my_screenInfo;
       //const QRect availableGeometry = m_screenInfo->availableGeometry();
   ```
3. Mod Shell height

   `nano shell/Shell.qml`

   ```
   Item {
       id: shell
   ...
       height: declarativeView.screen.availableGeometry.height - 28
   ```
4. Build it:

   ```
   cmake .
   make
   ```
5. Test it

   ```
   ./shell/app/unity-2d-shell
   ```

You may like to install it then rename it to avoid mess up with official one.

```
    sudo make install        
    sudo mv /usr/local/bin/unity-2d-shell /usr/local/bin/unity-2d-shell-mod
```