# Where does Banshee store playlists and podcast metadata?

Tags: banshee

I'm in the process of doing a system re-install. I've seen: [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

There are a couple of specific apps I want to double check that all their data/metadata will be saved if I copy my home directory (with hidden directories). So I wanted to ask where Banshee stores the metadata about podcast subscriptions, old vs new podcasts, and playlists, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be answered visiting the [Banshee FAQ](http://banshee.fm/support/faq/) page on their website, namely this section of it:

> `Where does Banshee store configuration files/the library database?`
>       It is stored under ~/.config/banshee-1/. The library database itself is called banshee.db and is a SQLite 3 database.

It is then kept at the home of the user under the folder `/.config/banshee-1/` and its a SQLite3 database.

To be able to open such a file you can use most of the SQL browsers out there that support SQLite3 file database connections.

One of such utilities is `sqlitebrowser`, look for it in the Ubuntu Software Center or install the package with `apt-get` in a terminal.

I am assuming that if you save the `.db` file (just copy it or the complete folder to another location) you will be just able to restore it to a new installation as long as the Banshee versions are not so far apart.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So as long as I copy /.config I'll be good.