# How to backup Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

I am very happy with Ubuntu, the way my friend set up all basic applications like libreoffice and web browser, Ubuntu rolls smoother than expected.

I am ex-windows user, just worried to back to everything with all softwares-n-settings preserved so that it can be re-installed if anything goes wrong.

Is there any way I can back-up everything like re-mountable ISO?

Please suggest the best method to back-up whole set-up for exactly same configuration so that I do not depend on my friend who set it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at Clonezilla. http://clonezilla.org/