# Replacing Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with 12.04 on dual boot?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partial-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on my laptop installed with the option to boot windows vista when I want to. How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS exaclty where I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS now without changing/affecting anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Install 12.04 on the partition that you have 10.04 on. However, you will lose all your installed softwares in 10.04. If you don't want that, you will have to go for a distro upgrade. But that might result in a lot of problems which you can find on this site itself. If you want the the softwares on 10.04 installed on 12.04 too, refer to this : [How can I duplicate my existing software packages on a new system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129182/how-to-install-the-same-softwares-in-12-04-which-were-there-in-10-04)

Comment: Yes, I see issues with distro upgrades, and the linked answer is the best way to go...

Comment: Make sure that you run the first command on 10.04 and save that 'packages' file somewhere before you wash away 10.04! I have both installed side by side so that I can switch between the two anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just upgrade to 12.04 if the goal is to swap 10.04 with 12.04. My buddy used a live disk to replace 11.10 with beta 2 and it acted like an upgrade instead. To initiate upgrade via manager hit alt+f2 then type `update-manager --d`.

Comment: Lots of bugs have been reported while running a direct upgrade. I would always recommend a fresh install and then installing the softwares from there.

Comment: if that is the case then I suggest anything you want to keep from 10.04, move it to windows.

Comment: True. But if the /home mount point is on a different partition, then there is nothing to worry about I guess.

Comment: thanx a lot guys. i really don't worry about my installed software. i know what i use and i can install it quickly again.
my only concern is that i don't want to mess up with many partitions. i just want to install the 12.04 exactly where the 10.04 is.