# /var partition ran out of space. Upgradation of softwares failing. Any workaround?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, memory-usage

When trying this : [How can I duplicate my existing software packages on a new system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129182/how-to-install-the-same-softwares-in-12-04-which-were-there-in-10-04) , after fetching all the packages, during the process of unpacking, my 2.88GB /var partition ran out of space completely.

Now when I try to run an upgrade or even a partial upgrade of the softwares that I have downloaded, my update manager is crashing and failing complaining that I do not have enough memory left in my /var partition which unfortunately, is true.

Is there a workaround for this problem? Attaching a screen shot of my hard drive partitions : [image]

/dev/sda11 is the one that has run out of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root partition seems to have more disk space. Boot into recovery console, mount `/dev/sda10` and `/dev/sda11` somewhere, copy all data keeping permissions from `/dev/sda11` to `/var` directory on `/dev/sda10`.

Then edit `/etc/fstab` to comment out the line which mounts `/var`. Reboot. Have fun.

To prevent this from happening in the future, I would then delete `/dev/sda10` and resize your root partition to use those additional 2.8Gb. There's really no benefit in having a separate `/var` partition if you have that little disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I followed the obvious way of jumping back to my 10.04 and shrank the 12.04 root partition and allocated that space to /var. Then I came back in to 12.04 and tried this :

```
sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

However, that told me I had messed up dpkg and I had to manually run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

in order to clean the mess up. I did so and again ran the first command which resulted in everything being installed correctly and peacefully. :)