# Can I keep my 10.04 installation and swap in ivy bridge CPU, motherboard and memory

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, hardware, intel-graphics, intel

I bought an i5-3570k CPU and an Intel DH77DF motherboard and memory and I was wondering if I can swap them in for my Core 2 Duo system and have Ubuntu 10.04 still work (keeping the hard drives).  Before the swap them in I was thinking of changing the video driver to Vesa (or can I just remove the xorg.conf file) and making sure I plug my hard drives in the correct order on the new motherboard.  Does anyone know if this will work?  Any other things I might have to do?

Comment: According to your new Hardware , Ubuntu 12.04 will be much better and will support your Hardware better and for longer time. If you are worried about reinstallation of your favourite applications , which you think might need efforts in searching and installing step by step , then please refer to have backups of Installed appplication list [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc), just add the revised PPA's for Ubuntu 12.04 version.

Comment: @tijybba Thanks for the link.  I'll use that when I upgrade.  Right now I don't care if the hardware is supported the best I just want to know if it will work (and be stable). I can use the vesa driver,  live without USB 3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend upgrading to 12.04 first. The newer libraries, drivers, and kernel in 12.04 have better support for the newer hardware. You can just move the xorg.conf out of the way, and keep it as a backup. It shouldn't be needed. But it is good to keep it as a backup, in case you need to plug your hard drives into the old hardware and boot there, because you find it isn't working well on the new hardware.

Comment: 12.04 will be better supported but that means I need to upgrade all my computers at once to 12.04 because older software isn't supported on 12.04 (and this is my server).  MythTV is the main culprit.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the older versions of specific software. From what I can see, mythtv is still in multiverse, and was there in 10.04 as well. And there's a newer version available in 12.04 which likely fixes many bugs, and possibly some security issues (I haven't looked at the change logs though). I'm also not sure what you mean about not supported there, as mythtv wasn't "supported" in 10.04 either, being in multiverse.

Comment: I'm on mythtv 0.23.  If I move to 12.04 then I must move to mythtv 0.25 (see [here](http://mythbuntu.org/repos)).  I would like to stay on 10.04 if possible as it is the most stable OS right now (my 12.04 test machine is giving those 'send error report' dialogs a lot).

Comment: Well, 10.04 should boot, and you should be able to run some applications, but you may have problems with the frame buffer, power management, and video, if you're not using an external video adapter, and not using the newer drivers. If you're running 32-bit 10.04, then you'll almost certainly need to install the -pae kernel if you aren't running it already.