# Should I backup /usr/local or not?

Tags: backup

Does it contain the only packages I installed manually from sources or with aptitude?

If so I think I can easily reinstall all packages I had installed with aptitude. Those few I built from sources are not much important to me to back them up.

Comment: Check this answer [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

Comment: Achu, thank you for useful link! I realised that my backup strategy is not the best to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it contain the only packages I installed manually from sources or with aptitude?

No, for me it's just stuff that I didn't install from the apt repos. Lots of Python libraries that I've installed with `pip`. And a few binaries in `/usr/local/bin/` (that either symlink out to Python or Doom 3 (which installs there too apparently).

In my case it's all stuff I'd reinstall in about five seconds with `pip` as I needed it... But I's strongly suggest you get an overview of what's there. Here are the two commands I used to look (you can probably use them elsewhere):

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

That shows you what's lurking in the local `bin` and that should be a good indicator as to what's *installed* in `/usr/local/`. For more depth I used:

```
find /usr/local -type d -maxdepth 4 | grep -v locale
```

Comment: Oli, thank you for sharing your knowledge! I checked out as you suggested and found out that my /usr/local contains  rvm, opera, hlds, duke nukem, ... not much stuff that I can easily reinstall. So, I excluded /usr/local from backing up. Best wishes, man!