# system very slow after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

After upgrading to 12.10 my system slowed down considerably. how can i make a new installation from scratch without loosing my adjustments? i have a dualboot system and a partition with all my personal files and data.

Comment: If it is something that was installed or changed that is causing the computer to slow down, restoring everything will put the system back exactly where it is now.  I do a proper answer for this one however.

Answer (score 1):

If the separate partition with all your personal data is a separate /home partition (recommended) then all or most of your settings will not be overwritten.  To restore installed programs you can make a list with *dpkg --get selections* and re-install them on the new setup.  Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) for a few different methods to do this, but I recommend the dpkg one if the system is the same release level.