# xml2-config is different from the same file on the system

Tags: apt, dpkg

I followed [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc/99151#99151) to restore a previously exported list of packages in a new system. At the end of the procedure, after `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y` I got this message:

```
[cut]lot of output, everything OK[cut]

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsensors4_1%3a3.3.1-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-4.4-base_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The full output is available on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1423409/). `/etc/sources.list` content is also available [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1423412/).

Then I typed again `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y`. This is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxslt1-dev:i386 : Depends: libxml2-dev:i386 (>= 2.6.26) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And trying to `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libxml2-dev:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxml2-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/761 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,206 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 372874 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libxml2-dev:i386 (from .../libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/bin/xml2-config' is different from the same file on the system
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Other people had similar problem and I tried to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/18140), but without being able to solve. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/libxml2/+bug/987502), I'm afraid. `libxml2-dev` is marked as being multi-arch co-installable, but it actually isn't.

Uninstall it: `apt-get remove libxml2-dev:i386`