# Least impact upgrade to latest ubuntu from old version

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, system-installation, software-installation, backup

I am looking to upgrade from 13.04 to the upcoming 13.10 but have a few questions about how to handle the upgrade whilst having the least impact on my current setup.

I have these partitions on my brand new SSD :

```
/boot - 512 MB
/ - 30 GB
/ - 30 GB (for alternate install, I like to try different distros on my laptop)
/usr/local/bin - 20 GB (contains all my dev env binaries like java6, java7, ant, sbt, eclipse, sublime text etc., manually installed by me)
/home - 65GB
swap - 8 GB (same as RAM)
data - remaining 70 GB
```

I have windows that came with the laptop installed on my slower 7200rpm spindle disk and am using its remainder 400GB as my primary data storage.

1. I am looking at the easiest way to upgrade with a clean install to the latest version of ubuntu while keeping the following intact :

   - (done) home folder (including ssh keys, wine, all user configurations, etc.)
   - user defined env variables used for development (pointing to `/usr/local/bin` in `~/.zshrc` for making commands like java, scala, ant etc available on CLI)
   - programs installed like f.lux, shutter, guake, clipit, terminator, git etc.
   - startup applications like skype, bitmessage, dropbox etc. [image: startup applications]
   - (done) custom ppa packages added
   - installed and configured app indicators
2. Should I change my partition strategy? im not aware if there is a better way of partitioning the disk to install all the operating systems according to my requirements.
3. What should my backup policy be? Should I create another partition on my spindle disk to save local backups? How big should it be? What folders should I backup?

To partially fill in the blanks for Q1. : I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243387/how-can-i-backup-my-programs-applications-so-that-after-i-reinstall-a-new-one) which helps in recovering the ppa list and installed packages. There is also [another link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) with a similar motive.

So my problem of ppa, installed packages, home directory is resolved. But im concerned about my `/usr/local/bin`, my startup applications and my installed app indicators. If my dev environment remains unaltered im happy.

Comment: You can always manually choose the partitions to be used in the install. Your startup applications should stay in your home partition and thus remain. Also, I don't think `/usr/local/bin` is necessary. I generally believe you should never manually touch anything outside of `/home`, `/media` and `/opt`

Comment: You can have multiple operating systems on the same btrfs filesystem (in different snapshots) with a little tweaking on /etc/fstab (mount option `subvol`). Pros: easy operating system version rollback, you could test a new release without losing the old one (snapshot the current subvolume, do-release-upgrade, do not delete the old OS snapshot until you're satisfied with the new one) --- share empty space (maybe you could afford even a third OS?) --- all the btrfs nice things like copy-on-write snapshots, etc.

Comment: @ignis +1 for the btrfs suggestion.

Comment: two things @minerz029 : + I had no idea that startup applications like the ones I have setup here : [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gI0G1Sp.png) will remain if I dont touch  my `/home` and + what is the purpose of `/opt` partition?

Comment: Your startup applications will remain but you'll need to reinstall the corresponding packages. `/opt` is used mainly as a place to unpack software which is in a `.tar.gz` file (at least for me), though Google Chrome does install to a subfolder of `/opt`. See the [FHS section on `/opt`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)

Comment: Everpad has no installable candidate under 13.10 (as of this moment).

Comment: `/opt` is "yet another" place for software not handled by the package manager, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544) and probably others.

Comment: IMHO 8GB of swap is a waste of space (only Windows is so memory inefficient). For proof of concept, load your system as heavily as you are likely to and open a terminal and issue the command `free` see: http://imgur.com/ohQGAhb