problems installing Ubuntu 24.04 on a machine a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04
I want to start Ubuntu from a clean slate, hence I want to install the new version instead of upgrading the current installation.
What I've done.

Backup all the important stuff
Create a USB stick with the ISO of Ubuntu 24.04
Secure Boot in Windows 10 is disabled.

Problem:
When following the installation options I don't get the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (image from this blog post).

I only get the two other options.

My understanding is you want to install a fresh version of Ubuntu 24.04 over the existing 22.04. Currently you do not have any unused disk space so it cannot install. To fix this you can select the third 'do something else' & select the partition you want to install it on which will be the one containing 22.04 and assign it to '/'. Alternatively, before installing &  using the install media in trial mode delete the old 22.04 partition using something like 'gparted' See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351092/if-i-choose-something-else-for-installing-ubuntu-20-04-in-which-partition-sho

Are existing installs UEFI and are you booting installer in UEFI boot mode. (or all old BIOS?) With multiple installs, best to make unallocated space either with Windows if shrinking NTFS or gparted on Linux formats. Then use Something Else to choose new install. Do you have separate /home or data partition(s)? Do not check format any partition other than a new / (root).

From a live Ubuntu session run: sudo fdisk -l, edit your post, copy and paste the output.
