# Install same packages from one server on another

Tags: installation, server, dpkg

I have a legacy Ubuntu Server 12.04 (i386) and a new Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (AMD64)

How do I use the same list of packages from the legacy server on the AMD64 server?
I tried this:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installedpackages
```

But when I use that list on the new server it tries installing i386 libraries and binaries. I don't want that. I only want the AMD64 stuff.

I used this post as a guide

[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this command line to generate your package list instead (you'll need to `apt-get install aptitude` if you haven't):

`aptitude search -F '%100p' '~i!~M' > installedpackages`

This should omit all those machine-specific preinstalled packages and only list things you deliberately selected (and their dependencies).

If even that has too much stuff in it, this should list more or less *just* the packages that you have explicitly installed (their dependencies will be pulled in automatically, of course):

`deborphan -a --no-show-section > installedpackages`

Comment: Consider that tip stolen as of now! -Thanks

Comment: @ScottGoodgame See the edit for another (possibly better) way.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Now I can migrate my configs from /etc, and  web apps from /opt and /var/www. Still working on getting all the MySQL grants from one server to another. Might replicate that DB.

Comment: @Malocchio On that topic, check out [this question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073808/copying-permissions-from-one-mysql-database-to-another).