# Installed software back-up

Tags: backup, restore, transfer

I have Linux Mint 15 Mate installed on one PC and I am currently updating it and installing necessary language packs, software, etc. After full set up can I back-up the entire system and restore it on another PC running same version of Linux (Mint 15 Mate)? Or at least restore all updated files and software? I am on limited Internet access and traffic is costy :(
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, this is Off Topic as it for Ubuntu instalations only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the entire system and then restore it on another PC, but it will completely replace the PC running the same version of Linux (Mint 15 Mate) with your cloned system. If that is something you want to do, see [this link](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8225-clone-your-ubuntu-installation-onto-a-new-hard-disk), which will guide you through installing and using gddrescue, which you can install with `sudo apt-get install gddrescue`.

If you just want to back up settings and installed packages, see [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc).

Comment: Well, second option is closer to what I want

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if this helped you too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform:

> dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/packages

This you create a list of the packages you have installed.

Then:

> cat packages > sudo dpkg --set-selections && sudo apt-get dselect upgrade

to install them back. A simple approach to have them in another HD would be to use [apt-offline](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline)[2](http://www.fifi.org/doc/apt/offline.html/ch1.html) - offline apt package manager