# Is there a way to create a CD with all my preset things?

Tags: system-installation

I have been using ubuntu and ubuntu based distros for quiet some time. However, every 2 or 3 months I reinstall (mainly change the distro to another one to test it) and I also install these systems on other laptops/PCs of friends.

The time-consuming part is where I change every bit to recreate my own settings that I find perfect for daily use. (meaning....icons, panels, conky, shortcuts, etc..)

Is there a way to create a live USB pendrive with all my own settings and install it from there? Saving the time of reconfiguring my system every time I install it on my computers of those of my friends?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Best way to backup all settings, list of installed packages, tweaks, etc?](http://askubuntu.com/q/9135/58950). Or at least, the backup and restoring of user settings...