# Upgrading from 14.10 to 18.04

Tags: updates, 14.10, 18.04

Due to injuries, I have been unable to use my computer since early 2015.  As a result, I have 14.10 on my system.  I'm getting "Failed to download Repository Information".  I've tried the solutions listed in 141512 with no joy.  How can I bring my installation current without dump / restore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [Reinstall Ubuntu keeping data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392294/reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-data) There are too many releases between 14.10 and 18.04 to skip over them, so you should reinstall the OS instead of upgrading it.

Comment: Did you set up your install to have /home on a separate partition?  If so, just do a "something else" install, formatting only /.  If no, you are faced with a choice: which is easier for you - back up your data and reinstall, or move your /home to its own partition, then do the "something else" install.

Comment: When running the solutions, did the errors change at all?  Can you add text from the failed upgrade to your question?  Last year I upgraded a version 13.10 to 16.04LTS.  I had initial errors but was able to work out the errors and have a stable upgrade that never experienced a glitch.  Starting over with a reinstall always work.  But you could also start out with working out the errors experienced in the upgrade process.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo do-release-upgrade`? :)

Comment: I get:  Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]                                        
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)

Comment: WARNING:root:file 'vivid.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.