# Cannot Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.10

Tags: 12.10, 14.04

Currently, I am using Ubuntu 12.10. When I open `Software Updates`, I find new release `Ubuntu 13.04` rather than `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Please Help!

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment which I've now deleted. 12.10 is still a supported release, but only for the next few days - probably why you're trying to upgrade.

Comment: Because some of my windows problem I cant install ubuntu alongside windows 8. The only version I can install successfully is 12.10. So I need to upgrade it.

Comment: Did you look at the ubuntu.com website concerning upgrade installs?  This type of information is documented there in great detail.

Comment: I know how to install ubuntu.But this time for some hard disk problem it is not possible to install other versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04.  Instead you will need to upgrade to the versions in between, in turn.  This means you'll need to upgrade first to 13.04, then 13.10, then 14.04.

The available upgrade paths between Ubuntu versions can be described like this:

- You can upgrade from any version to the immediate next version.
- If you have an LTS version you can also elect to upgrade to the next LTS version, skipping the versions in between the LTS versions.

If you are on a non-LTS version (such as 12.10) your only upgrade path is to the immediate next version.  To reach subsequent versions you must do multiple upgrades.  Or you could do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

You have upgrade to 13.04, 13.10 then to 14.04. If you want directly Ubuntu 14.04, download [Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) , make it usb/disc bootable with 14.04 then select `Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04`. This will upgrade whole Ubuntu except for `/home` directory (as it contains user data).

This will install fresh copy of whole Ubuntu, so before that backup your installed Softwares/packages & configurations with the help of this post. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

OR else just use this software [Aptik](http://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/) to avoid commands.

As per comments, do this Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. As you have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, make a DVD or USB bootable. This can be done with many different softwares. One of them is [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Select your platform on which you will be using this software to make USB/DVD bootable. Then follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvsDHM68jM8).

After making usb bootable restart your pc & go to `BIOS` or else just press `F11`/`F12` & select your pendrive name & select `Boot Priority Device` as your Pendrive.

Ubuntu 14.04 will start then select `Install Ubuntu` then after selecting place,keyboard settings(default), username & password, select `Upgrade to Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04`.This will upgrade your Ubuntu to 14.04. Now everything will be erased except for `/home` directory. Then again restore apps by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) post again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That second method is more of a fresh install than an upgrade. If "Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04" is what that option is called on the bootable install disc then that seems misleading to me - as it would wipe your entire install (including software selections and system-wide configuration) apart from the contents of your home directory.

Comment: neon_overload yes sir,softwares will be deleted but you can take backup of installed softwares/packages & their settings. I have edited my answer as I forgot to mentioned it.

Comment: @DpN sir can you be more specific that how can Upgrade to ubuntu 14.04? Because i have already downloaded "ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64"

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your comment. If any doubt comment here & if it helps then click on correct beside my post ! :)