# Is there a diff. or inc. backup with universal viewability

Tags: backup

Is there such a thing as a differential or incremental backup where you don't need a specific program - just a file browser - to view (the most recent/the least recent/any version of) backed-up files?

Also, is there any list of backup software/methods online where each entry says whether it saves the backup in a way that it can be easily viewed in a file browser? (or how specifically it saves the backup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two good references for different backup methods:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/jmburgess/Backup

[How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

I use the 'rsync' method myself, because I can simply view the backup files in a file browser.

The script I use for backup is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg --get-selections > ~/backupData/Package.list
sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* ~/backupData/
sudo apt-key exportall > ~/backupData/Repo.keys
rsync --progress --delete -a /home/chick/ /media/chick/Lbck/backup
```

This has the possibly questionable advantage of also backing up the list of installed packages, and everything in my home directory, onto a USB HDD.

Please note that this is not an exclusive list of how to do backups, but a pretty good list of inexpensive methods.  What is important here is that you *have* a backup to prevent those little times in life when everything goes south.

If you have the resources available, multiple backups using different backup methods is a great idea.

Comment: @karel  Thanks!  I'll expound upon my answer shortly...

Comment: "can simply view the backup files in a file browser" - This is exactly what I wanted. The links are useful, but do you know of any lists that mention if each one saves the backup in a way that it can be easily viewed in a file browser?

Comment: @enderforce Been out of town for a week.  The rsync method that I use is a step above making a brute force copy of the directory structure, and can be viewed with a file browser because it is literally a copy of the files on my drive.

Comment: I see. So it is kind of what I wanted, but I was hoping to have multiple versions of changed files available. (that part does not necessarily have to be viewable in a file browser)

Comment: You might check the jmburgess link in my original answer - The simplest version of versioned backups is rdiff-backup, followed by duplicity.  Graphical based versions include deja-dup, which is a front-end for duplicity