# `apt-get` suggests I remove `xinit`, how do I deal with that?

Tags: 12.04, xorg

I just updated my 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 to 64-bit version by taking the following steps:

- Made a tarball of my home (not really important)
- Saved `dpkg --get-selections`
- Made a tarball of `/etc/apt`
- Format and install latest 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04
- Overwrite home with the old home (again, not important)
- Overwrite `/etc/apt`

and to reinstall the old applications, I tried following from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/99151/31099), so I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dselect
$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
$ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

But, that was asking me to remove a lot of 64-bit packages and install the 32-bit versions of them. I didn't quite figure out how to reset the selection, so I just went ahead and uninstalled `dselect`.

Then I decided to go with a more manual method. Having the old `dpkg --get-selections` output (call the file `packages`), I did the following:

```
# take packages marked as deinstall
$ awk '/deinstall/{ print $1 }' < packages > deinstall
# and remove them
$ while read p; do sudo apt-get remove "$p" -y; done < deinstall
```

The removed packages were nothing weird. In fact, they were:

```
appmenu-gtk
appmenu-gtk3
asymptote
indicator-appmenu
libfltk-cairo1.3
libfltk-gl1.3
libgc1c2
libgsl0ldbl
liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0
liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0
libsigsegv2
libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
```

Then I did the same to install old packages (here I realized invoking `apt-get install` per package is too slow, so I did them all together):

```
# take packages marked as install
$ awk '/\tinstall/{ print $1 }' < packagespackages > install
# and install them
$ xargs sudo apt-get install -y < install
```

However, before doing that, I removed the packages that started with X, to make sure it doesn't do anything with X.

Doing this, it still told me some X related packages would be removed, but at the same time it said some other X related packages would be installed, so I let it do it.

Finally, what happened is the following:

1. On restart, X didn't run.  Trying FailsafeX said that `/usr/bin/X` does not exist. Following its suggestions, I did:

   ```
   $ cd /usr/bin; ln -s Xorg X
   ```
2. On restart, X ran ok and everything is ok.
3. When I do something with `apt-get`, it tells me that:

   ```
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     x11-apps libwayland-ltss-server0 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
     x11-session-utils appmenu-qt xserver-xorg-input-evdev x11-xfs-utils
     libxrandr-ltss2 xserver-xorg-input-wacom xinit xserver-xorg-input-mouse
     libxcb-xfixes0 libwayland-ltss-client0 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
     libllvm3.3
   ```

So here's my question. should I remove those packages? How can I make sure I have alternative packages so everything would work ok on restart? If I shouldn't remove these packages, how can I make apt understand that the system depends on them?

Comment: Did you, for some reason, remove the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage?

Comment: @muru, it seems so. Trying to install it says that it depends on `xorg`, but it's not going to be installed. Installing that says it has unmet dependencies. Do you know how I can automatically fix that (instead of tracing the packages manually one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As muru correctly suggested, `ubuntu-desktop` had somehow got uninstalled. It looks like somehow I had managed to replace X with wayland (maybe).

Installing `ubuntu-desktop` complained about broken packages `xserver-xorg` and `xorg`. Installing them, `ubuntu-desktop` was installed alright (and `/usr/bin/X` wad replaced). Apt still said some wayland packages are no longer needed, which I just `autoremove`d.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following steps next time the issue appears (Which are a bit excessive) but are used for cases where packages become annoying:

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

With that the packages should all be correct. There are worst cases where you would need to call upon the powers of `dkpg` and it's `--force-remove-reinstreq` or `--force-overwrite` parameters in order to "fix" the package.