# Can I switch from Ubuntu 14.04 to Lubuntu without losing my data and installed programs?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, graphics, lubuntu

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 on my very low end computer (it has pentium 4 2.8 GHz, with 1 Gb ram and 40 Gb HDD). The problem is that it gets really slow every now and then, though it is much smoother than Windows! However, am looking for something more buttery to use.

I have spent a lot of time (since I am new to Linux) in installing apps such as Red Eclipse, Google Chrome, uTorrent and many more into my current OS.

I have heard that Lubuntu would be the best choice for me, and have confirmed that with my own research on Google, as I would be using it for low end gaming, listening to music, web surfing, online gaming (Miniclip), movies, torrenting, some programming and some photo and light video editing.

How can I change from Linux Ubuntu to Linux Lubuntu without losing any data? Will my currently installed apps work on Linux Lubuntu as well?

Some additional questions:

- How can I make Lubuntu look better and really good to the eye after I have installed it?
- Are the terminal commands almost the same in Lubuntu as they are in Ubuntu?
- How would I connect my PPPoE connection in Lubuntu?

Comment: you can simply [download](http://lubuntu.net/) and install it as you did with Ubuntu, though if you want clean Lubuntu desktop it's better to format `/` during installation process because Lubuntu has its own set of packages to run but as stated in answer below you will lose data in `/` only if you [backup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) some of your data.

Comment: more detailed on backing up http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to install lubuntu from scratch, but you will need to install applications again. You can install lubuntu desktop by running

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

But some Ubuntu services will keep starting and making the system slow.

And yes, all applications will work on lubuntu. And terminal commands are same.

Comment: You will not be able to have the real fancy eye candy that probably have installed on Ubuntu.  LXDE was not made for fancy stuff.  It is simple and we like it like that.  If you want fast and simple that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reply in full and with sufficient precision to your question, however, I do have lubuntu running on mac, so, in the hope that someone more knowledgeable will chip in soon:
Yes, you can install lubuntu without loosing your data and applications. At login you will have to choose which front-end to load, unity or lubuntu.
You can install it via command line:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Or you can find it in the software centre. 
more info here: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

In general, I found most apps will work when switching between different front-ends, but not all the time. The main problems I had were with lesser apps, though, not well established ones.
Installing Lubuntu Desktop will install a range of apps which integrate well with Lubuntu and are light weight. You might find yourself with many alternative apps to what you already have with installed by default in unity.

You can  certainly customize Lubuntu a lot, as a starting point, it is very different from Unity, more like windows XP somewhat.
You might want to look into Enlightment too, which is a windows manager but very evolved and very light, so an alternative to lubuntu and unity. Again, you can install it and choose it at login.

Command line will be similar, commands you know and user in ubuntu will work exactly the same.
I cannot help you with pppoe, hopefully somebody will answer that :)