# Saving current configs

Tags: settings, ubuntu-core, nvidia-settings

Is it possible in 14.04 to save the current system settings?

I want (yet again) to install NVidia drives, but I'd like to save the current state of my settings and be able to roll back to the current state in case the drives don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable way to do this is to take a full backup of the drive. You can follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem so that you can roll back if the driver install fails.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link in another question which contains instructions (accepted answer) on how to do this:

[How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages)