# Clean Install after 15.10 video driver problem

Tags: 15.10

Upgrade to 15.10 failed to do video correctly.  Video works with live 15.10 DVD. Multiple install and uninstall of several different NVIDA drivers and Nouveau drivers no help.

Want to do clean install, but need to preserve packages and settings.  Aptik is GUI-oriented but does have command line options, but does not appear to do complete job.

What exists that will allow me to back up apps and settings, do clean install, then restore apps and settings?

OS is on one drive, Home directories are on separate RAID array; does this help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did purge Xorg and reinstall without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to backup settings and programs, I can recommend the answers to this post: [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages).

As far as the drivers issue goes, I'm not sure I can help. I'm running NVidia GTX 980M, and it updated fine, but it seems you might have a different issue considering you've tried many drivers.

Comment: If this answered your problem, please mark it as the answer so that other's know there's a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The Link to "How to backup settings and list of installed packages" was very helpful.  I also made a copy of /etc/passwd. I did that then found after the "clean install" I did not need to restore!  The "clean install" left all my packages there (except TrueCrypt disappeared).  When I reestablished my link to the home directory on the RAID array, The settings were generally restored.  Working well now. Thank you.