# How to get backup and restore the software from a unbootable hard drive

Tags: apt, partitioning, package-management, mount, backup

I have an Ubuntu partition that is unbootable although still mountable, and I'd like to create a newly installed system with the exact same packages as this system. The way to restore the list of packages I assume is to mount the unbootable root partition during a live-usb session and navigate to the `/mnt/var/lib/dpkg/` folder assuming its mounted on `/mnt` and perform `sudo dpkg -l --admindir > ~/Packages.list` which would produce a list file which could be manipulated to include 2 columns, one for the package name and the second is the word **install**. Then follow the something similar as the advice in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/99151) link. The problem is how to retrieve the apt keys from the unbootable partition.

I have seen many site that show how to backup and restore the apt keys from a bootable OS partition. The way to do this found at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/99151) link. There seems to be no information about how to automate the backup of keys from the mounted partition (un-bootable).

In a nutshell I would like to perform `sudo apt-key add ~/Repo.keys` in the newly installed system and retrieve all keys for `Repo.keys`. How to create this file from an unbootable system is what I need.

Can I just copy the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` file over to the new system and that's it? Or maybe a way to export the keys to a text file or something?

Comment: I followed the instructions in the links I provided and although there was a few errors concerning Packages/repositories it could not find due to not having the keys and repository locations, the majority was reinstalled under the new system. I then had to individually install keys and packages for those it couldn't find. These are mostly keys such as Ubuntu-tweak and others that aren't part of the ubuntu repositories. My home directory was just restored from a backup using live usb. Not sure if this answers the question I posed previously but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the drive from the live-usb session, do `chroot /mnt` (assuming the drive is mounted at /mnt), followed by the first three lines from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/99151) answer (as if the drive were bootable). Depending on the exact directory structure on that drive, you may need to replace `~/` with some directory that you know exists.