# issue after a dpkg --set-selections < packages-backup.list

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, backup, restore

I've create a backup of all the packages I've installed on one ubuntu server and try to restore it to a new ubuntu server.

I did the same as mentioned in the [first answer of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages)

Issue is after running the last two commands `sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list`& `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y`, I can't install new packages.

When trying to install `pip3`, I have this error

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

One of the solution I found was to do a `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

But when running the command, this the trace I have

```
[my:/home/my]$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up ppp (2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service gdm has to be enabled to start service pppd-dns
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ppp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pppconfig:
 pppconfig depends on ppp (>= 2.3.7); however:
  Package ppp is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pppconfig (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pppoeconf:
 pppoeconf depends on ppp (>= 2.4.2+20040428-2) | pppoe (>= 3.0); however:
  Package ppp is not configured yet.
  Package pppoe is not installed.
 pppoeconf depends on ppp (>= 2.4.1.uus2-4); however:
  Package ppp is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pppoeconf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ppp
 pppconfig
 pppoeconf
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first try removing `pp`. That's what seems to be causing your issues. So, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove ppp
```

Then, try installing `pip3` and whatever else you need normally.