# Restoring settings, apps, everything on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows, backup, hp, restore

First of all, I'm sorry for duplicating but I don't want any issues.

Hi, I want to install Windows 10 without any dual boot on my laptop (HP 250 G5), beacuse I want to update my BIOS, and the only way to update it is to run an exe.

How can I backup everything, from softwares installed, packages, repositories to settings, wallpapers, etc; and restore it, after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.

I have an 1TB external HDD if that helps.

Comment: "beacuse I want to update my BIOS" Why would you need a system with only windows on it for that?! If it is UEFI you do it from your BIOS by placing the windows executable in the EFI partition and telling your BIOS to pick it up. No need to mess around.

Comment: @Rinzwind it's UEFI (InsydeH20), how can I do that beacuse I don't see any thing to tell the BIOS to pick it

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03101724 is the official document

Comment: Here is one for a HP 250 G5 https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Update-BIOS-in-Ubuntu/td-p/6282901 person used another windows to extract but could have done that with 7z from Ubuntu.

Comment: Although tools such as clonezilla are popular, especially with Windows users, the backups are huge. IMO it is easier to back up home (which is where your settings are installed), and a list of installed apps. All the system files are recoverable from apt when you update from an install and all the system files are worthless as they will be over written the very next time you `sudo apt upgrade`. If upgrade produces a problem the solution is a bug report and you will hit the same problem w/ clonezilla. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages

Comment: I want to thank everyone for showing me, you just made my day easier! ;) Everything works well

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS doesn't have any "update" tools in itself.

- Download Clonezilla ISO latest version from its website,
- Create a bootable USB key with "Starup Disk Creator" software in your current Ubuntu installation.
- Clone your disk to your external HDD. Don't forget to check image health.
- Update your BIOS with your windows installation.
- Then recover your image to your HDD and continue to use your Ubuntu.