# After restoring image with Clonezilla, I can't boot.

Tags: boot, partitioning, backup, boot-repair, clonezilla

I am a beginner, I have backed up my Ubuntu 17.04 with Clonezilla to an external hard disk. My original Ubuntu OS mounted in a dual boot with Windows 10 in a SSD. I tried to restore the Ubuntu partition only and the system does not boot. I have set up the hard disk providing it with a swap partition and currently I am setting up a boot partition as well of 1gb (following a suggestion of boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition). Any command such as `fsck` did not help. I also tried to reinstall ubuntu 17.04 with a live USB but the installation stops - did not collect the error it returned me.

Comment: Cant really tell from what you posted. I suspect a hardware problem .

Comment: Hi Panther, i'll explain you my problem. I have a dual boot system(windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04). I would like to back up my Ubuntu partition and restore it into a new disk. This new disk will only have Ubuntu. I would like to clone the partition as I am not an expert and I have configured my Ubuntu a lot, therefore I would like not to lost any configuration as of now. Whenever I do the restore, the Ubuntu partition does not boot. Do you have any suggestion or method to suggest me? I'm using clonezilla. Do you think is a problem of hardware or grub? My original Ubuntu works fine.

Comment: Well that makes hardware less likely. To be honest, I am not a fan of clonezilla, you can back up a list of installed packages and user settings are in /home . I guess it would help if you were able to give us an error message of some kind

Comment: Hi Panther, could you please be more specific on the directories I need to backup? (i. e. Usr, Var, bin, etc..) also could you please give me the command to use and how to run it for both backing up and restoring, isuppose it is a 'tar' command. Should I run it from my original Ubuntu or from a live Ubuntu version?

Comment: There are tons of threads and as many opinions on how to backup. This is what I do - https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages/99384#99384. Basically back up a list of installed packages, /home, and any system files I edited, and any system data such as /var/www/html or mysql as needed.