# What are some aspects to consider when one needs to commit to a strategy, regarding LTS and non-LTS versions?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, lts

I use Ubuntu mostly to code, and I need performance because sometimes I play games on it. I also needed to install a lot of stuff.

I'm currently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I face the temptation of upgrading to the recently released 22.10.

But I seem to be aware that committing to a sequence of non-LTS releases may bring along some compromises.

What are the considerations that I should be aware of before making my decision?

Comment: It is up tp you to decide. Opinion-based questions are being closed by moderators.

Comment: Impossible to answer by us, It depends on what you use it for.  I reinstall every 6 months on my desktop My servers are on an LTS and stay on it as long as possible.

Comment: "better" depends upon your usage and preferences. Since we don't know anything about yours, we can only speculate. If you like to run newer software, and like to see what new changes have been made, than one answer is obvious. If you dislike changes don't mind older software, then another answer is obvious.

Comment: I use it mostly to code, and I need performance because sometimes I play games on it.

Comment: A good compromise would be to stay on 22.04 LTS, but upgrade to the [HWE-kernel line](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-generic-hwe-22.04). This will be upgraded along with newer Ubuntu releases.

Comment: In the last sections of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340797/1157519) you will find a few considerations introduced. When you mention coding, that rings a bell, because in LTS releases only older versions of various code interpreters / runtime environments will be available. So that would suggest going for the cutting edge Ubuntu versions. **Unless** you are using those "Foo Version Manager" type of installers, or if you are familiar with and don't mind [adding PPAs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html.en), because then an LTS may still suffice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, upgrading to 22.10 might not fix driver issues (rather it might cause some). You could try installing xanmod kernel, I found it is a lesser sacrifice that fixes my bugs and perhaps in your case, performance. Since xanmod on a uncongested Desktop runs on 1gb of ram at almost 0% CPU, in my case, not replicable with default Ubuntu fresh installs.

You can also boost performance with cpufreq or other CPU governor tinkering: just ramp up the clock...

Though if I were you, I'd take into account heat generation, since it might just end up causing your CPUs to thermal throttle or/and other damages on low quality plastic or the CPU itself (circumstantial stuff, depends on the quality of your casing/laptop and cooling capacity.

If your laptop usually overheats, do not casually boost your clock speed (I don't know whether you have that option available)

Answer (score 1):

It's already been mentioned in the answers to other questions that upgrading frequently to the latest version of Ubuntu provides the user with access to the latest security updates and new technologies at the expense of less stability in non-LTS versions of Ubuntu.

I've found it to be the case with Ubuntu 22.04 that it solved a few annoying graphics issues that I had with a new graphics card and an hwe Linux kernel on Ubuntu 20.04. You wrote in your question "I need performance because sometimes I play games on it". I didn't have any performance issues on Ubuntu 20.04, just a few minor bugs that seemed to be related to graphics processing. Stability and having no bugs is important to me, so I prefer to use LTS versions of Ubuntu.