# Lubuntu vs. Ubuntu + LXQt desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments

What is the difference between Lubuntu and Ubuntu with the LXQt desktop?

I understand that Lubuntu requires less resources, but I don't care about that - I'm on a high-end desktop that's plenty fast. I just prefer the LXQt DE.

Resource use aside, what are the differences between "real" Lubuntu and Ubuntu with LXQt?

For example, does it affect the support offered by Ubuntu Pro?

Comment: `I want to buy Ubuntu Pro support from Canonical` - Ubuntu Pro is free for individuals for upto 5 machines.

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi They quoted me $300/year. What's the difference between what you get for free and $300/year? I want to have somebody who will answer questions in (near) real time. (Phone or chat.)

Comment: The free subscription is for free extended upgrades beyond the regular 5 year lifespan of an LTS release. It does not have any phone/chat assistance.

Comment: `I want to buy Ubuntu Pro support from Canonical. Will they support either config equally?` -- You should contact Canonical about it. In this site, volunteers (not Canonical employees) answer questions about Ubuntu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks; I've split this into two questions.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I did ask them. See updated question.

Answer (score 2):

There is guaranteed support on packages found in `main` which include all the packages found on Ubuntu Desktop/Server etc. ISOs.

There is no guarantee on packages from `universe` or community supported beyond the 3 years, though all 'universe' packages can receive fixes during the normal 5 year cycle of a LTS by any MOTU, but teams offer only 3 years guaranteed support.

During the first three years of support; in my opinion there is no difference between *Ubuntu with LXQt*, and a Lubuntu system.  You could also extend that to the full five year cycle (*personally I'd call a Lubuntu system a Ubuntu system using LXQt after Lubuntu reaches EOL at the end of three years*).

After LTS has ended; or after the five years though; you'll need to read the fine print of what packages are included.  Canonical have published numerous '*indicators*' which read like a very large number of packages; but we don't know how they are calculated. They've specified some architectures are included; some are excluded, but even with that detail, it's clear to see only a small subset of packages are included in Ubuntu Pro support guarantees.

If you're using a Ubuntu LTS release past it's five years of *standard support*, I'd personally opt to use the default desktop (GNOME for recent releases). This applies with 12.04 ESM, 14.04 ESM & 16.04 ESM (*which used Unity 7 desktop by default*).  This '*opinion*' is based on reading the various notices/blogs put out by Canonical on this matter.

In a number of months we'll get more details about Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as it transitions to ESM/UA support, and when the full list of packages that will receive support are available, my opinion may differ to what is now (*which is based largely on prior 12.04, 14.04 & 16.04 facts*).  Whilst the number of packages has been increased *significantly*, we still don't know which packages are to be included on 18.04 and later ESM/UA support plans.

Comment: This answer is *OPINION*, and its not complete.   I've seen a benefit in the last few days with the ESM/UA plan that I don't mention in this answer, a benefit that may make it worthwhile for some business users, but I'm not going to look up what it was as it'd only be example.  I have no interest in backing this up with facts (*would take too long & little would be clear anyway as only limited facts are available except for 12.04, 14.04 & 16.04 which can be somewhat easily found*).  Further as Canonical publish a lot of blogs/notices that soon get deleted.. not all can be found...

Comment: If you (the OP) was after differences between Lubuntu/LXQt & Ubuntu/GNOME or the desktop, software stack (Qt5 vs GTK), etc.. I concentrated on the final "*offered by Ubuntu Pro*" part of the question, thus was using my *Ubuntu News* hat more than a *Lubuntu* hat.

Comment: From your answer I understand there's a difference in support after the first 3 years. That's fine - I'll upgrade before then. During the first 3 years is there any difference in Canonical's paid support offering (Lubuntu vs LXqt Desktop)? (I'm also very interested in technical differences - if any - but I realize your answer didn't cover that.)

Comment: Support; the Lubuntu 22.04.1 LTS announcement can be read here https://lubuntu.me/jammy-1-released/ or you can read a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS announcement here (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/) where it clearly states "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Core. All the remaining flavours will be supported for 3 years. Additional security support is available with ESM (Extended Security Maintenance).*"  Lubuntu is a *flavor* thus has 3 years of *guaranteed* support only; further 2 via community

Comment: Lubuntu is a Ubuntu system, being a *flavor* community packages are included, and we use the LXQt desktop & stack as our website indicates (https://lubuntu.me/).  Lubuntu's seed differs (contrast https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.jammy/desktop with https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/desktop which of course causes different packages to be included; we use Qt5 apps where we can so apps & desktop can share resources, but your question was not asking about LXQt vs GNOME as I read it given how it was written, esp. ending emphasis on pro/support.

Comment: When I say "support" I don't mean patches, updates, etc. I mean the paid service where somebody picks up the phone and answers questions ($300/year/desktop for 24x7). Is there a difference in Canonical's offer *of that service* for Ubuntu vs Lubuntu, or will they hang up the phone if I mention Lubuntu ("sorry we don't answer questions about Lubuntu - only Ubuntu")?

Comment: Lubuntu is a Ubuntu system (*as I already said*), the desktop however differs but Lubuntu does not offer paid support. If you're wanting clues as to what is actually included in a paid support contract (eg. https://ubuntu.com/pricing/pro) you'll note there are phone numbers & contacts (email etc) for questions on what is included/non-included within those contracts.  This is a community support site.

Comment: FYI:   Those *seed* files were intended as example... if you look there are other files too that may help clear the picture/understanding (or contrast *manifests* maybe too), but my point again was ***Lubuntu is a Ubuntu system***, built by the same infrastructure & tools that Ubuntu uses, from the same tools. It's just different packages that are included by default; chosen with a different intention, but this won't address your issue with paid support qeuries as that is a business decision to be made with the other party in the 'contract'.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to all this - I just looked at those seed files and see what you mean. (When you first mentioned "seeds" I thought you were talking about random-number-generator seeds...something something crypto signing). Let me try again to summarize my understanding: Functionally, installing Lubuntu on top of Ubuntu is equivalent to directly installing Lubuntu in the first place, except that there will be apps installed from Ubuntu that won't normally be used (so wasting some disk space, but in exchange for having them quickly available if wanted).

Comment: As per your other question, on multiple desktops I"ll refer you to a [link I wrote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278057/is-installing-another-desktop-environment-on-a-stock-ubuntu-20-04-install-consid) elsewhere on this site (*about my primary PC that (PSU) died somewhat recently forcing me to use others*). Lubuntu & Ubuntu use the same repositories, just different packages. Adding a second desktop will include the extra packages, thus extra disk space, more packages to upgrade (ie. bandwidth in updates etc) and be *functionally equivalent* .. but that is simplifying it a little too.