# Upgrade Ubuntu without getting a ton of new software installed

Tags: upgrade, package-management

Was asked to upgrade Ubuntu to version 11.10 today, and said alright. When it's asking me if I want to start the upgrade it lists some details. It says that 434 new packages are going to be installed. One is for example aisleriot, Solitaire card games. I do not want that on my system. I spent a lot of time uninstalling a lot of applications like that.

Is there a way I can tell Ubuntu to upgrade, without bringing with it a ton of extra packages that I don't want?

Comment: Usually, it will install upgrades of packages already installed and very few new packages. Did you have the solitaires and aisleriot already installed before the upgrade?

Comment: What are you upgrading from? If it's from before 11.04, it needs to upgrade these packages because of the transfer from gnome 2 to 3. If this isn't the case, there really isn't any way around it other than uninstalling all of the packages you don't want upgraded during the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installer will try to reinstall all the recommendations of `ubuntu-desktop`. This will draw in a lot of dependencies.

If you are feeling adventurous, you could:

1. Bypass the Ubuntu installer and manually rename all occurences of `natty` to `oneiric` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, comment all ppas, do a `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` on the command line. (This used to work on older debian, YMMV)
2. Dump your current packages as outlined in [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135) and [Backup Software Sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2038), do a basic command line install with debootstrap and play the packages back in.