# Backup ubuntu packages

Tags: backup

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system, and I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10. I want to backup the packages and list of added repositories. I made a déjà dup backup but I don't know if it backs up the packages. Also, can I restore a déjà dup backup made on Ubuntu 14.04 to an Ubuntu 15.10 machine?

Answer (score 0):

I use [aptik](http://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/) for this purpose. It serves to backup and restore your ppas and apps.  There are other functions as well, but I have only used those two.  It works well.

Comment: I tried aptik...But the size of the backup was just 5 MB...also, when I backed up downloaded packages, it backed up only one package...

Comment: You can export list of installed apps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages And lists of Sources: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2038/backup-software-sources But with sources be carefull. Some ppa may not have a compatible version with newer Ubuntu. Then you block all updates.

Comment: Aptik as I have used it only saves a list of apps. When you restore it downloads them again.