# Reinstall in new hdd restoring home folder. What happens to apps?

Tags: home-directory, restore, reinstall

I want to reinstall ubuntu (or maybe a different distro) to a new hard drive. I have the home folder backed-up using dejavu. I have the following questions:

When I reinstall ubuntu, and restore the home folder, will my apps be there too? Or will I have to reinstall everything and the configuration of each app will be there because I restored the home folder?

Comment: Aptik is really good. By using it and Deja-Dup I have just blown away a system (on purpose) and recreated it in only a hour or so.

Comment: And it was the same afterwards? Oh also, does it have a backup schedule? I would like to have the apps backed-up anyway, in case something happens. Like I do with deja's incremental backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use dpkg to export list of installed apps. I run it as part of my regular rsync script so backup has latest list.

From old install

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/my-packages
```

From New install

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < my-packages
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

IF you get this error:
dpkg: warning: package not in database

```
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dselect 
   -> Update
   -> Install
```

Also how to list applications you installed.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

http://askubuntu.com/questions/464701/find-out-what-packages-were-installed-after-os-install

But do not just import all sources as that can lead to issues of versions:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/2038/backup-software-sources

Answer (score 1):

The **`/home`** folder contains [usually] your personal files (documents, pictures, music, video clips ...) and your settings (tweaks).

But the apps, (application programs) that you have installed (and that do not belong to the basic installation) are stored elsewhere. They are not included in a backup of the `/home` folder or partition.

If you restore the home partition into your current system, the apps will not be affected, but if you create a new system, and use the backup to create your `/home` folder or partition, you have to install new versions of the apps.