# How to keep track of the installed software/system configuration to restore after a fresh linux install?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04

I have been thinking of writing some sort of utility for linux that keeps track of all my installed software and configuration. Something that after doing a fresh install I can just run it and will restore my copy of ubuntu as it used to be before doing the fresh install.

I do not know exactly where to start with this. I know that you can get a list of user installed software from `dpkg -i | grep ii`.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's easiest to just save $HOME.  Programmers do not have to follow standards, and even if they did, which standard?   ~./config, ~/.local ... and inside that if KDE/Qt (& version 3/4/5), likewise gtk-2/3/4 can each have their own folders.  People use apps from different desktops, plus 'forked' apps often change a local so people can have say `caja` & `nautilus` (of which caja was forked) & keep different configs for each, thus the location is slightly different...   Saving your $HOME is just easier, though directories like I mentioned would be my starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/955772/reinstall-in-new-hdd-restoring-home-folder-what-happens-to-apps